# Ruby- find strings that contain letters in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I've googled everywhere and can't seem to find an example of what I'm looking for. I'm trying to learn ruby and i'm writing a simple script. The user is prompted to enter letters which are loaded into an array. The script then goes through a file containing a bunch of words and pulls out the words that contain what is in the array. My problem is that it only pulls words out if they are in order of the array. For example...

```
characterArray = Array.new;
puts "Enter characters that the password contains";
characters = gets.chomp;
puts "Searching words containing #{characters}...";

characterArray = characters.scan(/./);
searchCharacters=characterArray[0..characterArray.size].join;

File.open("dictionary.txt").each { |line| 
    if line.include?(searchCharacters)
        puts line;
    end
 }
```

If i was to use this code and enter "dog"
The script would return
dog
doggie

but i need the output to return words even if they're not in the same order. Like...
dog
doggie
rodge

Sorry for the sloppy code. Like i said still learning. Thanks for your help.

PS. I've also tried this...

```
File.open("dictionary.txt").each { |line| 
    if line =~ /[characterArray[0..characterArray.size]]/
        puts line;
    end
}
```

but this returns all words that contain ANY of the letters the user entered

Comment: Instead of storing the search term as `"dog"`, store it as `'d','o','g'` and just check to see if every letter in the search array is in the word you are looking at.

Comment: Does each line in the file contain only one word?

Comment: yes. Only one word on each line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create `characterArray` yourself. When you assign result of function to a new variable, it will work without it.

In your code `characters` will be, for example, "asd". `characterArray` then will be ["a", "s", "d"]. And `searchCharacters` will be "asd" again. It seems you don't need this conversion.

`characterArray[0..characterArray.size]` is just equal to `characterArray`.

You can use `each_char` iterator to iterate through characters of string. I suggest this:

```
puts "Enter characters that the password contains";
characters = gets.chomp;

File.open("dictionary.txt").each { |line| 
  unless characters.each_char.map  { |c| line.include?(c) }.include? false
    puts line;
  end
}
```

I've checked it works properly. In my code I make an array:

```
characters.each_char.map  { |c| line.include?(c) }
```

Values of this array will indicate: `true` - character found in `line`, `false` - character not found. Length of this array equals to count of characters in `characters`. We will consider `line` good if there is no `false` values.